# VS2019: Why do I get range error when I try to create a new Web API 2 Controller - Empty?

Tags: windows-10, controller, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to create a new Web API Controller by adding a new scaffolded item.
As I try to name my new controller, I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647].
>   Parameter name: value'

This error seems to occur with any name, e.g. "DefaultController"

Is anyone familiar with this error?

A clipart of the error window in case it is of any help:

[image: error window]

Comment: I found this question on Stack Overflow. Seems to be for the same error. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436290/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-the-value-1-outside-t

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.4. The release notes are available here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.4